# How do I make the correct alignment button selected when file is opened?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, richtextbox, text-align

I have a richTextBox which the user can load a text file (rtf or txt) to. I have buttons which are used to align the text within the richTextBox. The issue is when the user loads the new document, if the text is aligned to the center, the align left (or which ever align button was last clicked) is still selected. How can I make the correct box highlight automatically (so if the first line of text is aligned to the center, the center button is selected, and if the second line of text is centered to the right and is then clicked, the right button is highlighted and the others are deselected?

Current code:

Left Alignment

```
 private void Left()
    {
        richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.GetLineFromCharIndex(1);
        richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.SelectionAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        if (left.Checked == true)
        {
            right.Checked = false;
            center.Checked = false;
        }
```

Center Alignment

```
private void Center()
    {
        richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.GetLineFromCharIndex(1);
        richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.SelectionAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        if (left.Checked == true)
        {
            right.Checked = false;
            center.Checked = false;
        }
```

Right Alignment

```
private void Right()
    {
        richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.GetLineFromCharIndex(1);
        richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.SelectionAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
        if (left.Checked == true)
        {
            right.Checked = false;
            center.Checked = false;
        }
```

This needs to be constantly updated so that when the user clicks a line, it gets the alignment status and checks the appropriate button.

Answer (score 0):

I have created sort of an notepad, with option to perform bold, Italic formating and so on. When a user click on a word that have any of this formating my button get highlighted. Maybe you can use the same in your project.

First I create an event on the richtextbox (selectionchanged).

After det I have inserted this code:

```
 if (Document.SelectionFont != null)
        {

            tb_Bold.Checked = Document.SelectionFont.Bold;
            tb_Italic.Checked = Document.SelectionFont.Italic;
            tb_UnderLine.Checked = Document.SelectionFont.Underline;
            tb_FontSize.Text = Document.SelectionFont.SizeInPoints.ToString();
            tb_Font.Text = Document.SelectionFont.FontFamily.Name;
            if (Document.SelectionAlignment.ToString() == "Right")
            {
                Center.Checked = false;
                Right.Checked = true;
                Left.Checked = false;
            }
            else if (Document.SelectionAlignment.ToString() == "Center")
            {
                Center.Checked = true;
                Right.Checked = false;
                Left.Checked = false;
            }
            else
            {
                Center.Checked = false;
                Right.Checked = false;
                Left.Checked = true;

            }

        }
```

And under each button I have this code:

```
Document.SelectionAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
        Center.Checked = true;
        Right.Checked = false;
        Left.Checked = false;
```

Of course change the alignement, and checkstatus for the button.